# Displaying a value as a symbol in Carto?

Tags: carto

I am working in Carto and have a geography (NYC Community Districts) and values associated with each community district (# of units built). I is possible to display those values as graduated symbols on a map?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it:

[image]

Image extracted from [CARTO Guides](https://carto.com/learn/guides/styling/style-by-value)

Comment: Thanks, but I am not seeing that option for this map; I only see the style by color option, not the aggregation.

Comment: @nyc123 no? What are you seeing?

Comment: Of the two options displayed in the image above, just the "Style" option (2 under the drop down menu). The  "Aggregation" option is missing.

Comment: @nyc123 ["Aggregation" option only appears on point data](https://carto.com/blog/exploring-big-datasets-with-carto/), but you can set style by value in any kind of shape (points, lines and polygons)

Comment: Is the style by value for polygons limited to just shading the polygon, or is it possible to display a value associated with the geometry as a point in the center of the polygon?

Comment: @nyc123 below Style there is a **LABELS** box (gif show it), active it and you can display any field inside/ in a vertex / line of the polygon. Also, you can set font, color, size, halo, etc

Comment: You can use a Find Centroid of Geometries analysis on polygons. If you want the result to include "yourunits" column then instead use SELECT ST_Centroid(the_geom_webmercator) as the_geom_webmercator, cartodb_id, yourunits FROM yourdataset. Then you can style points By Value as @aldo_tapia showed.